# How can I change the name of a dataframe in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to change name of existing data frame to newname that stored in variable.

```
newName = 'rSK_' + dimName.replace(' ', '') # rSK_TradeFlow
df.rename(newName) # this is not working
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the name of a particular Series (column)?  Do you want to change it in place or do you want back an altered copy?

Comment: Assuming you want to rename one Series of your DataFrame in place do `df2.rename(index=str, columns={oldName: newName}, inplace=True)`.  Add multiple mappings to rename more than one Series at a time.  See [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) for more.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, thanks for reply, I want to change dataframe name not columns

Comment: What do you mean by the DataFrame name?  How do you access it to show what it currently is?

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, yes I want to change DataFrame name, df to newDF without assigning data to newDF , In SQL we do exec sp_rename 'OldTableName', 'NewTableName'.

Comment: You want the DataFrame to be referred to by a different variable name?

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, yes...

Answer (score 3):

You actually have already achieved what you want when you assign the data to a new variable name.

Say for example you have a dataframe called `df_original`, if you assign it to a new variable called 'df_new' such as:

```
df_new = df_original
```

In this case, the data frame is NOT copied, it just gets a new name that refers to the original data saved in the memory.

If you run 'df_new is df_original' the output is 'True'. So these are just different names pointing to the same dataset saved in the memory.